# Search an array of words or a string with array of words using includes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, filter, include

I have a string or I can make it an array of strings. and when I try to filter it using includes if there are more than one search terms it doesn't return anything where is my mistake?

```
villas() {
    return this.$store.state.villas.filter((villa) => {
      return villa.f.includes(this.toFilter)
    });
  }
```

here is toFilter is the array of search terms
and f is the string i make the searching

Comment: If `toFilter` is an array, I'd think `villa.f.includes(this.toFilter)` would never work, not even when there's only one item in the array, because an array is never `===` to a string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I get your component has an array of "villas". Each of them has an `f` property. 
There's also an array `this.toFilter` which contains a  whitelist of words (search terms) and you want to filter the villas whose `f` property match the search terms.

If `f` was a string (like a description), a positive match would be when a string includes one of the search terms.

If `f` was an array (like, the tags of the villa) a positive match would be when there is an non-empty intersection between the tags and the search terms.

Fortunately both strings and arrays have a `includes` method, so the following should work either way:

```
villas() {
    return this.$store.state.villas.filter((villa) => {
      return this.toFilter.filter(term=>{
           return villa.f.includes(term);
      }).length>0;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you use the wrong syntax. If "this.toFilter" is an array and "f" is a string

> You should use: `this.toFilter.includes(villa.f)`

[includes](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes_array.asp)